# open scratch org with new user in terminal

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I want to open my scratch org with the same alias that I have nexmar in terminal but instead of system administrator open with my new user nexmar administrator that I make.

`sf org create user --set-alias testuser2 --target-org $ScratchName --definition-file config/project-user-def.json profileName='Nexmar Administrator' --set-unique-username`

And in this file I put the information of my user.
At the end I want to open my scratch org like this
`sf org open -o nexmar`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `--set-alias testuser2`, you can just assign it to your current alias e.g.: `--set-alias nexmar`. This will remove the alias from your existing user.